# 0x80300024 ("We couldn't get the drive online")

Tags: windows-10, ssd, installation

I'm trying to install Windows 10 onto an SSD which is connected to the computer by an Apricorn SATA wire.

When I get to the stage of the Setup which asks, "Where do you want to install Windows?", my drive shows up, but it says that the Free Space = 0 and the Type is Offline - as such, if I select it, the "Next" button is greyed out.

There's a warning at the bottom: 
"Windows can't be installed on drive 0 partition 1 (Show details)"

When I click on "Show Details", it says that the drive is offline and to Click OK to bring it online.

But if I click on OK, I get an error saying

> We couldn't get the drive online (Error 0x80300024)

Comment: Is this a new drive or a used one with partitions on it?

Comment: Try to disconnect any other hard drives you may have, except this one.

Comment: @harrymc - Thanks, I couldn't physically disconnect the other SSD because of how the device is built, but I disabled it in the BIOS. Once I did that I got back to the same screen and now a new error message tells me that Windows just doesn't allow itself to be installed to a USB connected SSD. :(

Answer (score 0):

I thought you meant that you connected the SSD as an internal disk.

Unfortunately, Windows Installer does not allow you to install to a USB flash drive.

The only solutions I can see are two:

- Connect the SSD as an internal disk
- Use a utility such as [WinToUSB](https://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/index.html)
  to create a Windows To Go Workspace from ISO, or
  clone the existing Windows OS to USB Drive as Windows To Go Workspace.

Comment: Rufus is another alternative

Comment: @Ramhound: I think Rufus will create a Windows installation media, rather than Windows To Go.

Comment: Rufus can indeed create a Windows to Go installation